# Вывод модального окна при нажатии на строку таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Необходимо сделать модальное окно. т.е. есть таблица и при нажатии на строку таблицы, должно открываться модальное окно соответствующее этой строке. и вот у меня не получается сделать что бы для каждой строки было свое модальное окно(открывается постоянно одно и тоже).Таблица генерируется циклом.

есть такой блок с таким id

```
<div id="myModal${id}" class="modal fade">
```

как в js получить этот ${id}?

```
var id = ?????????

$("#myModal"+id).modal('show');
```

Comment: `как в js получить этот ${id}?` - так при клике на строку таблицы ты же можешь получить её номер сверху. это и будет `id`

Comment: ведь id достаются из базы и вдруг в базе была удалена какая нибудь строка получается id в базе будут идти таким образом после удаления 4ой строки - 1.2.3.5.6.7 и если мы будем брать индекс строки и считать его за id то у нас будет выводиться не та информация

Answer (score 0):

С учетом того, что при клике на строку таблицы мы можем получить индекс этой строки (правда начинающейся с нуля), то всё становится очевидно

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var idx = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('.modal').hide();
    $('#myModal' + idx).show();
});
```

```css
div.modal {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}


table {
   border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;  
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">1</div> 
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">2</div> 
  <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade">3</div>   
<div>
```

Хотя непонятно зачем столько модальных окон. Вообще достаточно иметь только одно, но давать ей всегда конкретные данные для отображения. А то представь,  у тебя 100 строк. Что, лепить 100 модальных окон? Это же нерационально.

Comment: я наверно не правильно выразился. как передавать в одно мадальное окно конкретные данные

Comment: @ONYX ...... к чему тогда вот это: `myModal${id}` и это `$("#myModal"+id)`?  ...получается тебе надо просто писать так  `$('.modal').modal('show');` ....... вставив при этом до показа необходимые данные в этот `div`...

Answer (score 0):

добавьте атрибут в каждой строке при генерации:

```
<tr data-id="{id}">
```

вызвать его можно будет так:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $('.modal').hide();
    $("#myModal"+id).modal('show');
});
```